# Web app Telegram. Загрузка нескольких файлов

Tags: javascript, android, telegram-bot, web-apps

Задача: загрузка нескольких изображений в web app telegram

Проблема: на андроиде в браузере все ок, а вот в тг, в боте, не дает даже несколько изображений выбрать. На ios работает везде

Работаю через обычный input внутри формы (React):

```
<input accept="image/png, image/jpeg" multiple type="file" id="files" />
```

или:

```
<input accept="image/png, image/jpeg" multiple={true} type="file" id="files" />
```

Есть предположение, что дело в самом Telegram для Android... Но может кто-то уже пробовал решать такую задачу?

Тестовый бот с формой kalininabot_bot 
Полностью код формы: https://github.com/oksan4ik10/testbot-react/blob/master/src/App.tsx